# Method name suggestion for clone-like method

Tags: naming-conventions

Objects in my open-source toolkit are all based on the class AbstractObject. I want to add a function into AbstractObject which will create and return object of the exact same class.

This is different from cloning, because the property values are not copied. I thought about calling it `duplicate` but it is confusing when working with ActiveRecord classes (as duplicate would be used to duplicate record, not object).

```
form2 = form1->createObjectWithSameClass()
```

Please suggest a single-word (preferably) name for this. I appreciate your time!

Comment: Is the new object related to the one on which the method is called in any way besides sharing its type?

Comment: they share same parent in object run-time tree. (like a dom tree) other than that - no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information here, this sounds like you want another plain object of the same **type** as a variable in scope, and that **type** is the only context needed when creating the object.

In that case, this sounds like a valid case for a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead of a method hanging off of an instance.  You could do, perhaps:

`myFactory.create(form1)`

or

```
myFactory.create(form1.getClass())
```

EDIT: this is not a direct answer to your question, but because you are concerned with naming, and therefore I assume with clarity of code, one of the big benefits of a pattern is clarity (everyone knows what a Factory is, so they won't be confused by whatever name you end up choosing).

Comment: Ok, using existing convention as my muse, you should call the method `newInstance()`, simply because `newInstance()` is the same name as `Class.newInstance()`.  If a reader of your code understands the behavior of `Class.newInstance()`, then I hope they think your own `newInstance()` method does the same thing.